# Onde ficam armazenados os objetos criados em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, orientação-a-objetos

Fiz um pequeno *script* para registrar dados dos alunos onde trabalho. Eu consigo instanciá-los e consigo ver os dados logo após. Mas, após sair do programa, estes dados se perdem.

Estes objetos só ficam armazenados na memória enquanto o programa está aberto? Eu teria que criar um dicionário dentro do programa para armazenar estes dados? Pode parecer uma pergunta simplória, mas não consigo achar resposta.

Segue abaixo o construtor que criei:

```
class Diploma:

    def __init__(self):

        self.nome = input("Aluno: ")
        self.curso = input("Curso: ")
        self.registro = int(input("Registro: "))
        self.sistec = input("SISTEC: ")
        self.livro = int(input("Livro: "))
        self.pagina = int(input("Página: "))
```

Logo após seguem os *getters* e *setters*.

Comment: Objetos são sempre criados em memoria, se os quer persistir precisa de os guardar em algum lado como banco de dados ou arquivo. Agora se a pergunta é se o objeto que representa cada diploma se perde enquanto o programa está a executar, já tem a ver com o seu código e se você o guarda em alguma coleção

Answer (score 6):

Sim, todos os objetos criados somente existem na memória RAM, e a mesma é desalocada quando se fecha o programa. Se quiser persistir os dados, é necessário armazená-los em um tipo de armazenamento persistente, como o HD ou o SSD.

Porém, estas formas de armazenamento não armazenam objetos, e sim *bytes*, sendo assim, é necessário **converter** os objetos que você quer armazenar em *bytes*, de uma forma que seja possível convertê-los novamente de volta nos objetos em um outro momento da execução do programa. Esse processo é chamado de **serialização**.

Existem vários módulos para auxiliar neste armazenamento, de funções simples de manipulação de arquivos até *ORMs* que são modelos relacionais de objeto, podendo armazenar em um banco de dados com serialização automática dos objetos.

No caso da sua classe, você colocou a leitura dos dados a partir do usuário, no `__init__` - isso não é muito prático, pois significa que a sua classe não pode ser instanciada sem pedir dados para o usuário. Seria ideal mover a leitura do usuário para uma função separada, para facilitar a leitura dos dados de outro lugar que não seja `input`.

Outro detalhe é que você mencionou *getters* e *setters* porém no python eles **não são uma boa prática** como no java. Você os usa raramente em forma de `property`, mas só quando eles forem realmente necessários.

Finalizo a resposta com um exemplo simples para armazenar sua classe em um banco de dados SQL usando a biblioteca `sqlalchemy`:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Unicode, Integer
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///escola.db', echo=True)
Base = declarative_base(bind=engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

class Diploma(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'diplomas'

    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    nome = Column(Unicode(200))
    curso = Column(Unicode(200))
    registro = Column(Integer())
    sistec = Column(Unicode(200))
    livro = Column(Integer())
    pagina = Column(Integer())

    @classmethod
    def ler_do_usuario(cls):
        d = cls()
        d.nome = input("Aluno: ")
        d.curso = input("Curso: ")
        d.registro = int(input("Registro: "))
        d.sistec = input("SISTEC: ")
        d.livro = int(input("Livro: "))
        d.pagina = int(input("Página: "))
        return d

Base.metadata.create_all()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = Session()
    # cria um diploma a partir do usuario:
    d = Diploma.ler_do_usuario()

    #armazena o diploma no banco de dados:
    s.add(d)
    s.commit()

    # le o primeiro diploma a partir do banco de dados:
    d2 = s.query(Diploma).get(1)
    print(d2.nome)
```